# Using FunctionTransformer with sklearn Pipeline and ColumnTransformer - error: invalid type promotion

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using pipeline for preprocessing data. Here is my code. I want to convert a string column to datetime and replace empty strings ('  '), "N.A" with `np.nan` for some other columns. I'm trying to use `FunctionTransformer` in my pipeline steps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'categoric1':['Apple', '  ', 'Cherry', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Cherry', 'Orange'],                    
                   'numeric1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],                                      
                   'numeric2':[7,8,9,"N.A", np.nan, '  ', 12],
                   'date1': ['20001103','20011109', '19910929', '19920929', '20051107', '20081103', '20101105']})
cat_features = ['categoric1']
num_features = ['numeric1', 'numeric2']
date_features = ['date1']

print(df.head(7))

def replace_with_nan(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()       
    X_copy[X_copy == '  '] = np.nan
    X_copy[X_copy == 'N.A'] = np.nan
    return X_copy.values

def square_values(X):
    return X**2

def convert_to_datetime(df):
    df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], errors='raise') #df['date1'].astype(str) + "Z"
    return df

cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ft_replace_nan', FunctionTransformer(replace_with_nan, validate=False)),    
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')),   
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(categories=[['Apple', 'Orange', 'Cherry']], handle_unknown='error'))     
])

num_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[    
    ('ft_replace_nan', FunctionTransformer(replace_with_nan, validate=False)),
#     ('ft_square_values', FunctionTransformer(square_values, validate=False)),    #Another FunctionTransformer -----1
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

date_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[    
    ('convert_to_datetime', FunctionTransformer(convert_to_datetime, validate=False))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough', transformers = [
    ('num', num_transformer, num_features),
    ('cat', cat_transformer, cat_features),
    ('date', date_transformer, date_features)
])

# ft_fill_nan = FunctionTransformer(replace_with_nan, validate=False)
# transformed_data = ft_fill_nan.fit_transform(df)
# print(transformed_data)

# ft_convert_datetime = FunctionTransformer(convert_to_datetime, validate=False)
# transformed_data = ft_convert_datetime.fit_transform(df)
# print(transformed_data)

transformed_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)
print(transformed_data)
```

[image]

**Questions:**

1. When I try to execute `preprocessor.fit_transform(df)`, I'm getting
   errors as below. Can you please help how do I fix this?
2. What if I want to execute another FunctionTranformer in same pipeline to square
   the values by uncommenting line `#Another FunctionTransformer -----1`. Is it possible? If so, how?
3. I don't want to change the state of the actual data inside
   `convert_to_datetime(df)` method above. I would also want to make it generic without accessing actual `date1` column. How Can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You are getting `invalid type promotion` error, because of heterogenous data type. Sklearn is trying to concatenate using numpy struct arrays internally.  Solution is extracting necessary features from the date, for example month of the given date.

All you need to change is the `convert_to_datetime`

```
def convert_to_datetime(data):
    return data.apply(lambda x: [pd.to_datetime(date,  format="%Y%m%d").month for date in x])
```

By doing this way, you don't have to hard code the column name inside the function.

result:

[image]

2. you can add one more functional transformer easily, try this!

```
    ('ft_square_values', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x*2, validate=False)),    #Another FunctionTransformer -----1
```

3. By adopting the solution mentioned in point 1. you can get away from this problem as well.